# Determine if a point is contained in the circle in 3d space

Tags: circles, 3d, parametric

I have a problem where I need to determine if a point is contained in the area of a circle in 3d space.

For my circle, I have the radius (R), the position of the center (C) and a normal vector to the circle (N). With that, I can easily draw my circle.

Now, I will have a point generated and I want to know if this point is located on the area of the circle.

Currently, I'm thinking of obtaining the parametric equations of my circle which are:

\begin{align*}
x &= r\cos\phi\cos\theta \\
y &= r\sin\phi \\
z &= r\cos\phi\sin\theta
\end{align*}

Then, I could easily verify if the point verifies these equations.

However, I don't know how to convert the data I have (Radius, Center position and normal vector) into these 3 parametric equations and I need help with that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my opinion,
1. check if $|CP|\leq R$
2. check if $\vec{CP}\cdot N = 0$

more specifically, if $C = (x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ , $N=(a,b,c) $ and $P=(x,y,z)$

P is on disc C when,

1. $(x-x_{0})^{2}+(y-y_{0})^{2}+(z-z_{0})^{2}\leq R$
2. $(x-x_{0})*a+(y-y_{0})*b+(z-z_{0})*c=0$

the second condition ensures that P is on the same plane as the disc.

Comment: What do you mean by vertical, parallel ? I think I should check also that the distance between C and P is smaller than the radius right ?

Comment: I meant perpendicular *

Comment: Yes, you should check if CP is smaller than R.

Comment: if CP and N are perpendicular, P is on the same plane with the disc.